# How to use Ilogger in my bot's custom action components?

Tags: c#, botframework, bot-framework-composer

Note: this is for bot framework composer projects.

I have setup serilog to be my implementation of ILogger and it works fine inside the root project (the actual chatbot) but not inside my custom action components.

I am aware that Ilogger works via Dependency Injection but I just can't figure out how to make it work inside custom action components. It always returns null in the constructor.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public class SendSMSPaymentInformation : Dialog
{
   private readonly ILogger _logger;

   [JsonConstructor]
   public SendSMSPaymentInformation(ILogger<SendSMSPaymentInformation> logger, [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "", [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
       : base()
   {
       RegisterSourceLocation(sourceFilePath, sourceLineNumber);

       _logger = logger;
   }
  ...
```

I assume something has to be defined inside the "BotComponent" configuration method, but I am not sure what.

I should also clarify that I want to avoid using Serilog's static Log class as much as possible and not tie myself to a specific logging provider.

Comment: How is your DI Container configured?

Comment: @Jodrell I have added "services.AddTransient<MyClassLibrary>();" inside the ConfigureServices method that each component has. This doesn't seem to work. I have tested out the exact same thing with just a regular default asp.net core project and it works fine there.

EDIT: for good measure I also added the AddTransient inside the Startup.cs file but to no avail.

Comment: but, have you done something like this https://andrewlock.net/adding-serilog-to-the-asp-net-core-generic-host/, so that the DI container knows how to instantiate and inject an `ILogger<T>`

Comment: DI doesn't seem to work for bot framework composer projects. Whatever magic is happening under the hood it killed DI for custom bot components. I just made a static library that I load up with my loggerfactory in program.cs and then call the loggerfactory in custom bot components

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/introduction?tabs=v2x, for those looking

Comment: You need to add the logger to `ConfigureServices` when you define your `BotComponent` I assume. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-create-custom-actions?source=recommendations#create-the-botcomponent-class

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

dc.Context.TraceActivityAsync(...) ?

or you can pass the **ILogger BotController ** to custom action but It's not the best way because the logger always "BotController" class name even if you are using the Bot component class

Comment: Mind giving me an example?

Comment: @Vinoth Rajendran, is it possible to get the logger from the dialogContext? not entirely sure I can't remember where I seen the code snippet, but something like ex: `dc.services.get......` ?

Comment: Have you tried

dc.Context.TraceActivityAsync(...